# Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a collection of countable sets. Prove that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ is countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I'm a recent HS graduate, and this is my proof for this statement. It feels very informal and loosey goosey. What are your thoughts?

Here are some definitions I'm working from: (1) 2 sets X and Y have the same cardinality (Card(X)=Card(Y)) if there exists a bijection f: X --> Y; (2) Consider the set n = {1,2,3, $\cdots$, n} for any positive integer n. Then a set S is finite if card(S)=card(n) or card(S)=card($\emptyset$); and (3) A set S is countable if either S is finite or card($\mathbb N$)=card(S)

Q: Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a collection of countable sets. Prove that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ is countable.

A: I will show that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ is either finite or $card(\mathbb N)=card(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n)$.

In the $card(\mathbb N)=card(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n)$ case, suppose that $x_{11}, x_{12}, \cdots$ denotes the first, second, and so on element in a countable set, $X_1$, and $x_{21}, x_{22} \cdots$ denotes the first, second, and so on element in a countable set, $X_2$. We can construct a grid of values such that $j$ denotes the $j$th element in the $i$th countable set. In short, $X_{ij}$ denotes the jth element in the ith countable set, assuming such an element exists.
[For some reason, my diagram isn't properly rendering, and so here's a link to the proof technique I'm using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLeM6.gif]

We construct a function $f : \mathbb N \to \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ as follows: let $n=1$ and starting from the top left node, $x_{11}$, assign n to it, and then follow the arrows, incrementing $n$ by 1 and assigning that new $n$ to the next node. However, if a node appears more than once or there does not exist an element $X_{ij}$ at that node, skip it. In short, map 1 to $x_{11}$, 2 to $x_{12}$, 3 to $x_{21}$, and so on.

We know this function is injective because whenever $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, $x_1=x_2$, since each element in the image is hit exactly once, by construction. This function is also surjective because each $X_{ij}$ in the codomain corresponds to an $n$ in the domain. Thus, $f$ is bijective, and we conclude that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ is countable.

In the finite case, to show that $card(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n)=card(\{1,\cdots,n\})$ for a positive integer n, we construct a function $g : \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n \mapsto \{1,\cdots,n\}$ in the same way as above, but switch the domain and codomain.

Comment: Note that the result is more or less equivalent to showing that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: How? I know how to show that by diagonalization.

Comment: How's my proof?

Comment: The proof looks reasonable to me. Some proofs are inherently messy.

Comment: @copper.hat Is it too informal though? I'll try to write a proof using the method you provided.

Comment: Actually, I think you are missing something. If $X_1$ is countable, how do you get an 'arrow' from the $X_1$ elements to the first $x_2$ element? The arrows are essential in your argument to define the bijection.

Comment: Basically like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLeM6.gif

Comment: I see, I missed that above. I think it might be clearer to show how your map creates a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and then show how a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to X$ can be converted into a bijection?

Comment: I'll do that now

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_k$ is countable, there is a surjection $b_k:\mathbb{N} \to X_k$.

Then $g(k,l) = b_k(l)$ is a surjection $g: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \cup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$.

Hence $| \mathbb{N}^2| \ge | \cup_{n=1}^\infty X_n|$.